# How do I create and perform set operations using Spark SQL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've used Spark SQL to create an array of IDs called `todays_ids` and `previous_days_ids`. I'd like to be able to use Spark SQL directly to convert these arrays of IDs into sets, and then calculate the difference between one column's IDs and another column's IDs. So far, I've used a UDF:

```py
df = spark.sql("""
... query to generate today and previous day's ID array columns
""")

# udf that calculates a size of the difference between two sets 
differencer=udf(lambda x,y: len(set(x)-set(y)), IntegerType())

df = df.withColumn('difference', differencer('todays_ids', 'previous_days_ids'))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("differences")
```

I can then take the `difference` column and compute a "freshness" score for how much the IDs change each day relative to the previous day.

Is there a way I can accomplish this via Spark SQL, and not using UDFs? I can't find anything in the [Spark SQL documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html) about using sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size` and `array_except` should be equivalent to your operation of `len(set(x)-set(y))`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('difference', F.size(F.array_except('todays_ids', 'previous_days_ids')))
```